# Build linux kernel 4.15.0-22 scripts/Makefile.clean

Tags: 16.04, kernel, compiling, packaging

I want to compile linux-source-4.15.0-22 on xenial(16.04-4). When i use the following command I have received an error.

```
make clean distclean && make mrproper && make-kpkg clean
cp /boot/config-4.15.0-22-generic .config
make-kpkg --initrd kernel_source -j8
```

The error is:

```
tar: crypto.master: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

Some lines after that the following error is announced:

```
scripts/Makefile.clean:15: crypto/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'cryptMakefile'. Stop
Makefile:1347: recipe for target '_clean_crepto' failed
make[2]: *** [_clean_crypto] Error2
make[2]: Laving directory '/home/hassan/linux-source-4.15.0/debian/linux-source-4.15.17/usr/src/linux-source-4.15.17'
.
.
.
```

Please help me to compile this.

More information:

```
    install -p -o root -g root -m 644 ./debian/pkg/source/copyright '/home/hassan/linux-source-4.15.0/debian/linux-source-4.15.17/usr/share/doc/linux-source-4.15.17/copyright'
echo "This was producted by kernel-package version 13.018." > \ 
    /home/hassan/linux-source-4.15.0/debian/linux-source-4.15.17/usr/share/doc/linux-source-4-15.17/Buildinfo
r cf - $(echo * | sed -e 's/ debian//g' -e 's/\,deb//g' ) |  \
    (cd /home/hassan/linux-source-4.15.0/debian/linux-source-4.15.17/usr/src/linux-source-4.15.17; umask 000; tar xspf - )
tar: crypto.master: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous error
(cd /home/hassan/linux-source-4.15.0/debian/linux-source-4.15.17/usr/src/linux-source-4.15.17/include; rm -f asm ; )
install -p -o root -g root -m 644 debian/changelog /home/hassan/linux-source-4.15.0/debian/linux-source-4.15.17/usr/src/linux-source-4.15.17/Debian.src.changelog
(cd /home/hassan/linux-source-4.15.0/debian/linux-source-4.15.17/usr/src/linux-source-4.15.17; 
    \
    /usr/bin/make ARCH=x86_64 distclean)
make[2]: Entring directory '/home/hassan/linux-source-4.15.0/debian/linux-source-4.15.17/usr/src/linux-source-4.15.17'
  CLEAN   .
  CLEAN   arch/x86/purgatory
scripts/Makefile.clean:15: crypto/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'cryptMakefile'. Stop
Makefile:1347: recipe for target '_clean_crepto' failed
make[2]: *** [_clean_crypto] Error2
make[2]: Laving directory '/home/hassan/linux-source-4.15.0/debian/linux-source-4.15.17/usr/src/linux-source-4.15.17'
debian/ruleset/targets/source.mk:35: recipe for target 'debian/stamp/install/linux-source-4.15.17' failed
make[1]: *** [debian/stamp/install/linux-source-4.15.17] Error 2
make[1]: Laving directory '/home/hassan/linux-source-4.15.0'
debian/ruleset/local.mk:96: recipe for target 'kernel_source' failed
make: *** [kernel_source] Error
```

Comment: is it possible to have more information? We didn't know what is `crypto.master` but I know it may not be possible with confidentiality

Comment: Hi @damadam , I have updated the question.

Comment: that didn't bother me, but you re asking a Debian problem on an Ubuntu forum, not sure some people will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way, create link crypto.master from crypto and build again.

```
make clean distclean && make mrproper && make-kpkg clean
ln -s crypto crypto.master
cp /boot/config-4.15.0-22-generic .config
make-kpkg --initrd kernel_source -j8
```